# Plotly: How to rotate yaxis title in a facet grid?

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

[image]

Hi there, the issue as you can see is that the title squeeze into together on the right, is there any way to rotate it?
Thanks a lot.

```
fig = px.box(df, 'deposit_amt', color = 'class', facet_row= 'Age_Group')
```

Comment: Try `fig.update_yaxes(tickangle = 90)`

Comment: sorry, that does not work as this is actually the title of yaxis. I didn't find any syntax for the axis title which confuses me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change subplots title position/orientation in Plotly Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399439/change-subplots-title-position-orientation-in-plotly-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer here will most likely depend heavily on how you've built your figure. You see, what you're trying to fix here is in fact the `angle of some annotations`. And if you're right that what appears as messed up text in your figure are in fact title of the yaxis, you can just build your plot using a slightly different approach and then use

```
for annotation in fig['layout']['annotations']: 
    annotation['textangle']= 0
```

I'll use the dataset stored in `px.data.tips()` to show you what I mean. That dataset seems to resemble your real world dataset to a satisfactory degree. It's at least possible to build this figure out of it:

[image]

Now, apply the snippet above and you'll get:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.box(df, x="tip", y="sex", facet_row='time', color = 'time')

for annotation in fig['layout']['annotations']: 
    annotation['textangle']= 0

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 6):

There is actually a much better solution to this, if you facet by columns and you force it to have 1 plot per row it will format the titles much better.
Note that you might need to adjust the facet_row_spacing

```
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.box(df, x="tip", y="sex", facet_col='time', facet_col_wrap=1, color = 'time')
fig.show()
```

[image]