# Can you alter a subplot title location in plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, subplot

When adding a subplot_title to my subplots in plotly my title overlaps with my axes. Can I alter the location of the subplot title like matplotlib's `ax.set_title('title', y=1.5)`?

Here is my plot, as you can see danceability overlaps:
[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
categories = ['key', 'acousticness', 'danceability', 'energy',  'loudness',
         'speechiness', 'tempo','key']

fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{"type":"polar"}, {"type":"polar"}]],
                    subplot_titles=('Clustering Into 8 Playlists', 'Clustering Into 11 Playlists'))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
          r=x,
          theta=categories,
          fill='toself',
          name='Cluster 1',
           visible='legendonly'
    ), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatterpolar(
          r=y,
          theta=categories,
          fill='toself',
          name='Cluster 2',
           visible='legendonly'
    ), row=1, col=2)

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=1400, title_text='Radar Plot of All Clusters (Fig.4)')
fig.show()
```

Comment: Since the axes do not overlap in my environment, can you provide a graph of your current situation?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I gave a partial code answer, but you can do it with `fig['layout']['annotations']`. From the official reference [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/annotations/#layout-annotations-items-annotation-yanchor).I also referred to [SO's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399439/change-subplots-title-position-orientation-in-plotly-python).

```
fig.update_layout(title_text='Radar Plot of All Clusters (Fig.4)') # height=600, width=1400, 
for annotation in fig['layout']['annotations']: 
        annotation['yanchor']='bottom'
        annotation['y']=1.1
        annotation['yref']='paper'
        
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I had a similar problem with subplot titles on a 2 x 2 grid. The answer was simply

    fig.update_annotations(yshift=20)